# Going from an Entity_id to an instance of an entity in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am having some trouble figuring out how to go from form data containing IDs for each foreign key to an actual model made with fluent NHibernate.

Say for example we have a class:

```
public class Subcategory
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

and it's map:

```
    public SubcategoryMap()
    {
        Table("subcategories");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        References<Category>(x => x.Category);
    }
```

Now when someone posts form data to create a new `Subcategory`, it comes in as an ID (int). I am using Automapper BTW. What is the appropriate method (with or without Automapper) to go from the model received from the client:

```
public class SubcategoryDTO
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Category_id { get; set; }
}
```

Back to the `Subcategory` class above?

Surely I don't have to actually query the DB to get the `Category` in question, assign it to the `Subcategory` then save the `Subcategory`...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You want use the Load() method on the session.

Here's a very old article explain the syntax.

https://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id

The key piece is

> This is how NHibernate maintain the OO facade when giving you the same
>   optimization benefits of working directly with the low level API.

is that you don't need to fetch and hydrate a whole object from the database.

The Load() syntax takes care of of all that.

so

```
session.Save(new SubCategory { 
    Name = subCategory.Name, 
    Category = session.Load<Category>(subCategory.Category_id) 
};
```

will make 1 trip to the database

I don't think you can achieve this using Automapper.